# Run a query with an if condition on the same query

Tags: mysql, loops, while-loop, case

IF the the number of ROWS in the QUERY A is greater than 5, THEN show the ROWS of Query A. If it is less than 5, then try 10 more times to pass the condition. IF it doesn't meet the condition after 10 tries, then LEAVE.

```
Set try=0
   While try <10:
   IF (select count(*) of QUERY A) > 5
      EXECUTE QUERY A
       Leave while
   ELSE       
   try=try+1
```

Is this possible in a MySQL statement?

Comment: your question is not clear  ..  
"I would like to run a query if the COUNT(*) of the query is greater then a given number."  .. for get the count you must execute the query  ..  try add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: IF the the number of ROWS in the QUERY A is greater than 5, THEN show the ROWS of Query A. If it is less than 5, then try 10 more times to pass the condition. IF it doesn't meet the condition after 10 tries, then LEAVE.

Comment: what are you trying to solve with this piece of code? This seems like a maniacal approach compared to something else

Comment: @user10316146  the comment have not sense  in sql  .. "If it is less than 5, then try 10 more times to pass the condition". .. if you try 10 times the same query  ..  you have 10 times  the same value  ..  should be better if you try to explain you real goal ..for this code sample  .